# How-to limit number of pages generated with SQL result

Tags: php, sql, count

I have a pretty nice system in my code which puts my SQL result on different pages, 10 rows on each page. This is great and works exactly the way it should, but I would like to limit the number of pages generated. My result is in a specific order, but after 25 pages I think it's enough (that would be 250 results). What do I add to the code below in order to maximize the amount of pages created? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php 

// First I build my SQL which counts the amount of 
// rows, how this SQL query looks like depends on the 
// fields left blank and actually filled.

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(bedrijfsnaam) FROM profiles";

if ($bedrijfvariabele != " zoek op bedrijfsnaam.." && 
    $bedrijfvariabele != "") 
{
    $sql .= " WHERE bedrijfsnaam = '".$bedrijfvariabele."'";
}

if ($rubriekvariabele != " zoek op rubriek.." && 
    $rubriekvariabele != "" && 
    $bedrijfvariabele != " zoek op bedrijfsnaam.." && 
    $bedrijfvariabele != "") 
{
    $sql .= " AND (hoofdrubriek = '" . $rubriekvariabele . "' "
          . " OR subrubrieken LIKE '%" . $rubriekvariabele . "%')";
}

if ($rubriekvariabele != " zoek op rubriek.." && 
    $rubriekvariabele != "" && 
    ($bedrijfvariabele == " zoek op bedrijfsnaam.." || 
     $bedrijfvariabele == "")) 
{
    $sql .= " WHERE (hoofdrubriek = '" . $rubriekvariabele . "' "
          . " OR subrubrieken LIKE '%".$rubriekvariabele."%')";
}

if ($plaatsvariabele != " zoek op plaatsnaam.." && 
    $plaatsvariabele != "" && 
    (
        ($bedrijfvariabele != " zoek op bedrijfsnaam.." && 
         $bedrijfvariabele != "") || 
        ($rubriekvariabele != " zoek op rubriek.." && 
         $rubriekvariabele != "")
    )) 
{
    $sql .= " AND plaats = '".$plaatsvariabele."'";
}

if ($plaatsvariabele != " zoek op plaatsnaam.."  && 
    $plaatsvariabele != "" && 
    (
        ($bedrijfvariabele == " zoek op bedrijfsnaam.." || 
         $bedrijfvariabele == "")  && 
        ($rubriekvariabele == " zoek op rubriek.." || 
         $rubriekvariabele == "")
    )) 
{
    $sql .= " WHERE plaats = '".$plaatsvariabele."'";
}

// Now comes the interesting part for you guys

$rs_result     = mysql_query($sql); 
$row           = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages   = ceil($total_records / 10); 

$template = '<a style="float:none;display:inline-block;color:white;'
          . 'width:22px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;'
          . 'font-size:20px;background-color:#483435;margin-left:4px"'
          . ' href="%s".php?page=%s">%s</a>'; 


for ($i=1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) 
{
    echo sprintf($template, $plaatsnaam7, $i, $i); 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you simply need to use a LIMIT keyword on your query.

Try something like this:
    SELECT * FROM PEOPLE LIMIT 10

Comment: Yeah, just adding `LIMIT 250` to the end of the query should be exactly what the OP is asking for...

Comment: That's the same thing I was thinking. Using a limit statement should also speed up the query time, and reduce memory overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, i went with the other method, but I bet this would have worked just as good! Would this method speed things up?

Comment: While I'm by no means a DBA, I would venture to guess that pulling a limited group of records would be faster then pulling all of the records and limiting what is displayed through the PHP interpreter. Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 1):

from

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a style=\"float:none;display:inline-block;color:white;width:22px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;background-color:#483435;margin-left:4px\" href='".$plaatsnaam7.".php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 

};
```

to

```
if $total_pages>25 $total_pages=25;
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a style=\"float:none;display:inline-block;color:white;width:22px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;background-color:#483435;margin-left:4px\" href='".$plaatsnaam7.".php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this 'pretty nice system '. I big mistake is to load a hudge amount of data which may never be shown. You should load just the slice you need to show - as you said 10 rows per page. you should use SLQ limit clause - `LIMIT offest, rowcount` - example `select * from mytable order by id limit 20,10` - will show 10 rows, starting form the 20th in the results ordered by id. you should pass a GET or POST param setting the number of current page 'page=2' and $ofsset = 10*($page-1); $rowcount = 10; `'select .... LIMIT '.$offset.','.$rowcount`.

Look at this old but nice class which perfectly shows a good pager system: [split_page_results.php](http://www.codeforge.com/read/172915/split_page_results.php__html). Some parts should be rewriten to follow the new PHP rules, but the idea is clearly implemented.

Here yopu can find an usage hint: [enter link description here](http://www.codeforge.com/read/172915/product_listing.php__html). Good luck.

Comment: I actually WOULD call this a 'nice system' since what you describe is exactly what i've done. However, what you are referring to is outside of the code I posted. I never actually posted the actual SQL which loads en shows all the result, did I? The SQL you see here just counts the rows that the same query printed out. Thanks for you help, but read more closely before you condemn my system..

Comment: Ok, just showing a good example how to do it right. At least this is a `class` working well and tested with the years. If you think that's useless, you just ignore it. Not knowing the basic LIMIT clause usage is showing that you are not good with SQL and making inline CSS instead of assigning a class, shows other week points. Just wanted to show you a good example in general which looks much better than you have shown here. Your will, just ignore my answer.

Comment: Your answer was not useless in any way, don't take my answer the wrong way. I actually did now the LIMIT clause, my mind was just fixated on limiting the number of 'numbers' appearing, in stead of thinking about the possibility of limiting in actual COUNT SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Just let an `if` statement check which page you are on.